# having trouble with XAMPP; $_POST php not working

Tags: php, xampp

I have a problem with $_POST function. 
I have this simple code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
    <body>
    <?php
if (isset($_POST["password"])){

echo $_POST["password"];
};
?>
<form action="" method="POST">
    Password: <br>
    <input type="password" name="password"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT">

</form>

    </body>
</html>
```

I run this code on [PhpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/) and it work as it should. However, when I running this on my laptop I get this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: password

Thanks for your help. I am running XAMPP control pannel v3.22. IDE:PhpStorm. Php version: 7. OS: Windows 10.
I even asked this question here:

[$_POST not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37004229/post-is-not-working-php-7?noredirect=1#comment61561947_37004229)

Comment: Do you see anything if you `var_dump()` your `$_POST`?

Comment: @EatPeanutButter this is what I get: array(0) { }

Answer (score 1):

You are missing to place a value inside the `action` attribute in your form. Replace this code:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
```

with this code:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="POST">
```

The previous php code inside the action attribute informs the `form` that the input should be sent to the same page. The `htmlspecialchars()` function is used to prevent XSS attacks on your site.

**EDITED:**

You also forgot to place a closing parethesis. Replace the following code:

```
if (isset($_POST["password"]){
```

with

```
if (isset($_POST["password"])){
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: thanks for the answer, unfortunately still not working. I have tried this code on  http://phpfiddle.org/ (which is online PHP coding) and this code works. But I do not know why it is not working on my laptop.

Comment: at what point do you get the error message? Is it only wen you click the "SUBMIT" button or is it even before you click submit?

Comment: @m.akbari I edited my answer, let me know if it works now

Comment: if i get rid of isset($_POST) i will get when I load the page. How ever, still not getting $_POST["password"].

Comment: @m.akbari what about the parenthesis modification, did it work?

Comment: there was a parenthesis in my original code. Here in my code, I miss typed it. I will edit the question.